# How to check if TD is last with class in row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a large HTML table with dynamically added rows.

The table has a standard structure (incl. thead, tbody and tfoot).

Within this table there are editable TDs (which have the class "`editable`" and contain a contenteditable div) and non-editable TDs (which dont't have the class "editable" and do not contain a div).

If a user is in such a div I would like to **check if** the current (closest) TD **is the last TD within the same row that has a certain class** ("`editable`").

I tried the below but this doesn't work here. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

**My jQuery (in doc ready):**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var current = $(e.target);
    // ...
    if($(current).closest('td').is('td.editable:last')){
        alert('last editable td in current row'); // test alert
    }
    // ...
});
```

**My HTML (example row):**

```
<tr>
    <!-- ... -->
    <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td> <!-- editable -->
    <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td> <!-- editable -->
    <td></td> <!-- non-editable -->
    <td></td> <!-- non-editable -->
    <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td> <!-- editable -->
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) like

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var editables = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.editable')
    var count = editables.length;
    if(editables.index($(this).closest('td')) == (count - 1))...
});
```

The above should not return an index if `closest('td')` does not have class `editable`

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  var editables = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.editable')
  var count = editables.length;
  console.log('Is last editable td: ' + (editables.index($(this).closest('td')) == (count - 1)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- ... -->
    <td class="editable">
      <div contenteditable="true">test</div>
    </td>
    <!-- editable -->
    <td class="editable">
      <div contenteditable="true">test</div>
    </td>
    <!-- editable -->
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true">not editable</div>
    </td>
    <!-- non-editable -->
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true">not editable</div>
    </td>
    <!-- non-editable -->
    <td class="editable">
      <div contenteditable="true">test</div>
    </td>
    <!-- editable -->
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true">not editable</div>
    </td>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Update: This looks very interesting but I couldn't get it to work. Wouldn't I need something like $(current).closest('tr').find... here to always refer to the current row ?

Comment: @keewee279, take a look at the code snippet and let me know if you have anymore quetions

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works great and actually better with than the other approach. Will accept this one. Thanks again ! :)

Comment: Ammar! Congratz... `Plus1` from my side too!

Answer (score 5):

Try the `:last-of-type` selector? Never use `:last` or `:first`, as they are implemented differently in every browser!

```
if ($(current).closest('td').is('td.editable:last-of-type')) {
```

Comment: But isnt it possible last-of-type will match a td without .editable?

Comment: It includes classes. Not attributes. `:D` So this works!

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Sorry, since I am new to this I would like to also ask about the following to make sure I get this right: This will only refer to the current row (tr), which is what I need, correct ? Also, is there an opposite "first-of-type" as well ?

Comment: Update: Thanks again. I tried this and it works fine within the rows but I couldn't get it to work at the end of the rows so I accepted Ammar's solution. Thanks anyways for your help !

Comment: Okay, no problem... `:)`

Comment: Do you have a source for :last and :first being implemented differently in every browser? I would assume they're implemented the same way considering their implementations are provided by jQuery itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siamakferdos/jja8wg8g/1/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true">11</div></td> 
        <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true">22</div></td>
        <td>33</td> 
        <td>44</td> 
        <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true">55</div></td> 
    </tr>
</table>

 $("table tr td.editable").keydown(function(){   
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    if(col == $(this).parent().children().size() - 1){
        alert('last editable td in current row'); // test alert
    }    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/alaingoldman/5cseugvs/1

Basically what i did is i targeted the table tag and looked through it's descendants with the pseudo class last-of-type.

Hopefully this helps. Cheer.s

```
$('table tr:last-of-type').css({backgroundColor: "pink"})
```